# Need support for Split screen support React native Android

Tags: android, react-native, split-screen

I have been creating eCommerce app in react native . I have some doubts on split screen support.

App Screens are working fine if view has scrollView but screen without scrollview will not work.

I have doubts in following

1. Is there any specific code for it?
2. If any official tutorial is there for split screen work?

Thanks in advance.